# When I resize the window to a small size content to the right is cut off.

Tags: html, css

When I resize the window to a small size content to the right is cut off.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> -->
    <title>Ingrid Voz</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

 <section class="about">

        <h2 id="trabajo">Cómo trabajo</h2>
        <p id="about-subheading">Déjame adivinar cómo quieres tu trabajo…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="about-container">
            <div class="col a"></div>
            <div class="col b">
                <i class="fas fa-plane"></i>
                <h3 class="about-h3">¿Lo quieres rápido?</h3>
                <p class="about-p">Una virtud que destaca en mí es mi lealtad por mi trabajo. Me gusta ser rápida contestándote y entregándote la
                grabación de tu proyecto.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col c">
                <i class="fas fa-trophy"></i>
                <h3 class="about-h3">¿Quieres profesionalidad?</h3>
                <p class="about-p">La rapidez no es suficiente si no mantienes una ética de trabajo completa. Cuando amas lo que haces los clientes lo
                notan. ¡Echa un ojo a las opiniones de mis clientes!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col d">
                <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                <h3 class="about-h3">¿Quieres un precio justo?</h3>
                <p class="about-p">Dependiendo del tipo de proyecto que tengas, el precio y la entrega variarán, ¡pero siempre será un precio justo y
                adaptado para ti!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col e"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=row>
        <p class="your-voice">¡Entonces soy tu voz!</p>
        <div class="btn-container">
            <a href="#" class="quote">¡Pide tu presupuesto!</a>
        </div>


</section>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}




* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

about, .contact {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(237, 99, 117, 0.9), rgba(237, 99, 117, 0.9)), url(Images/thumbnail_section\ COMO\ TRABAJO.jpg); 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;

}

.about:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    content: '';
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-top: -35px;
    background-color: #D65A6A;

}

#trabajo {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 150%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#about-subheading {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.about-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 120px 1fr 1fr 1fr 120px;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.col {
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 20px; 
    padding: 20px;
}


.fas {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: white;
}

.fa-plane {
    transform: rotate(320deg);
}


.about-h3 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.about-p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.your-voice {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.quote {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.quote:hover {
    color: #D65A6A;
    animation-name: btn-bounce;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

This is just an example of one section as I didn't want to put in too much code but I have the same problem on over sections of the site as well. It is responsive to a certain point when scaling down but then when it reaches a certain point content on the right hand side starts to go missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which content? Can you replicate the behaviour on codepen or jsfiddle? I couldn't replicate the issue, but just from looking at the code, the two "candidates" for a potential problem are `body {overflow-x: hidden;}` and `.about.contact {min-width: 100%;}`. Btw, you have a typo there and you need a dot before `about`. Is there a reason you were using `min-width: 100%`?

Comment: Thanks i'll replicate it tonight when I'm back at my computer. Sorry for the type... That was just from copy and pasting. When I take over overflow hidden then I'm left with white space at the side. Min-width was just something i was trying out in frustration haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using bootstrap 3 framework to make this website responsive. So try to use bootstrap classes as much as possible to construct layouts.

Refer bootstrap grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Listing few issues below:

Close the meta tag because of this the bootstrap classes are not working

From

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
```

To

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

In CSS change .about-container properties to this. Use media query if you want to set the width for smaller devices.

```
.about-container {
     max-width: 80%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .about-container {
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 15px;
    }
}
```

In HTML change the following:

From this

```
<div class="about-container">
            <div class="col a"></div>
            <div class="col b">
                <i class="fas fa-plane"></i>
                <h3 class="about-h3">¿Lo quieres rápido?</h3>
                <p class="about-p">Una virtud que destaca en mí es mi lealtad por mi trabajo. Me gusta ser rápida contestándote y entregándote la
                    grabación de tu proyecto.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col c">
                <i class="fas fa-trophy"></i>
                <h3 class="about-h3">¿Quieres profesionalidad?</h3>
                <p class="about-p">La rapidez no es suficiente si no mantienes una ética de trabajo completa. Cuando amas lo que haces los clientes lo
                    notan. ¡Echa un ojo a las opiniones de mis clientes!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col d">
                <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                <h3 class="about-h3">¿Quieres un precio justo?</h3>
                <p class="about-p">Dependiendo del tipo de proyecto que tengas, el precio y la entrega variarán, ¡pero siempre será un precio justo y
                    adaptado para ti!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col e"></div>
        </div>
```

To This

```
<div class="about-container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <i class="fas fa-plane"></i>
                <h3 class="about-h3">¿Lo quieres rápido?</h3>
                <p class="about-p">Una virtud que destaca en mí es mi lealtad por mi trabajo. Me gusta ser rápida contestándote y entregándote la
                    grabación de tu proyecto.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <i class="fas fa-trophy"></i>
                <h3 class="about-h3">¿Quieres profesionalidad?</h3>
                <p class="about-p">La rapidez no es suficiente si no mantienes una ética de trabajo completa. Cuando amas lo que haces los clientes lo
                    notan. ¡Echa un ojo a las opiniones de mis clientes!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                <h3 class="about-h3">¿Quieres un precio justo?</h3>
                <p class="about-p">Dependiendo del tipo de proyecto que tengas, el precio y la entrega variarán, ¡pero siempre será un precio justo y
                    adaptado para ti!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```